# Applying effect on all pictures in folder (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple code, that applies effect on one of my pictures:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

path_in=os.path.join("C:/Users/Desktop/Images","glass.jpg")
img = cv2.imread(path_in, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

but problem is, that I want to apply this to all images in my folder and I don't know their names.

So I understand that I need to create loop with the list of my images in folder, but I have tried this and it didn't work

```
path_in=os.path.join("C:/Users/Desktop/Images")
list = os.listdir(path_in)
for img in list:
    img = cv2.imread(path_in, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
io.imsave("C:/Users/Desktop/Images_new", image_converted)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I would be very glad if someone could tell me, what I am doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the right track. There are just a few minor issues with your code:

First, define the `path_in` inside the loop and join your folder path with the image name. Second, never use keywords from the python language as variable names. The name `list` is a python keyword.

I don't know the functions `imsave`, `imshow` and `show` in details, so I'm not sure if they should be inside of the loop. I guess, but there you may need to just test it. Also, for `imsave`, it may be that you need to set a path for each image. In that case you could do it like `io.imsave("C:/Users/Desktop/Images_new/{}".format(img), image_converted)`.

```
path_folder = "C:/Users/Desktop/Images"
img_list = os.listdir(path_in)
for img in img_list:
    path_in = os.path.join(path_folder, img)
    img = cv2.imread(path_in, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    io.imsave("C:/Users/Desktop/Images_new", image_converted)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

No 100% guarantee it works exaclty as is. Let me know if you get an error.

Answer (score -1):

```
path_folder = "C:/Users/Desktop/Images" 
img_list = os.listdir(path_in) 
for img in img_list: 
    path_in=os.path.join("C:/Users/Desktop/Images",img)
    path_out = os.path.join("C:/Users/Desktop/Images_new", img) 
    img = cv2.imread(path_in, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
    image_converted = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
    io.imsave(path_out, image_converted, format = 'jpg') 
    plt.imshow(image_converted) 
    plt.show()
```